# Passing variable from subroutine in tk perl interface

Tags: perl, variables, tk-toolkit, subroutine

I am using the perl Tk interface where I want to have a button test_1 and upon clicking on this button I would like a variable $varchoice to be defined as test_1.  If I press on the button test_2, the variable $varchoice should be defined as test_2.

Before is the snippet of code in which I attempted to accomplish this:

```
$budget_frame->Button(-text => 'test_1',-command => sub{$varchoice=budget_plot_1()})->pack(-side => "left");
$budget_frame->Button(-text => 'test_2',-command => sub{$varchoice=budget_plot_2()})->pack(-side => "left");

sub budget_plot_1()
{
    print "plotting 1\n";
    my $var=1;
    return $var;
}

sub budget_plot_2()
{
    print "plotting 2\n";
    my $var=2;
    return $var;
}
```

How do I tweak this code to get the desired results?

Comment: I am assuming you declared `$varchoice` in the beginning of your script. Then your code seems to work as you require, except currently you set `$varchoice` to `1` and not `test_1`.. If you set it to `test_1` it will work exactly as you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program seems to work fine. Here is an example of how I tested it:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $budget_frame = MainWindow->new(-title=>"Button test");
my $varchoice;

$budget_frame->Button(
    -text => 'test_1',
    -command => sub{ $varchoice = budget_plot_1() }
)->pack(-side => "left");
$budget_frame->Button(
    -text => 'test_2',
    -command => sub{ $varchoice = budget_plot_2() }
)->pack(-side => "left");
MainLoop;
say "Value of \$varchoice = $varchoice";

sub budget_plot_1()
{
    print "plotting 1\n";
    return "test_1";
}

sub budget_plot_2()
{
    print "plotting 2\n";
    return "test_2";
}
```

**Output**:

```
Value of $varchoice = test_1
```